# Redirect API endpoints in nginx

Tags: nginx

There is an API deployed on the server. I have a public IP to which I want to connect the domain. Normally it works this way: 127.0.0.1/api/v1/register, but the domain looks like api.mydomain.com, so I don't really need the part "api/v1". How can I redirect all users' requests like "127.0.0.1/register" into "127.0.0.1/api/v1/register"?

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/{{ SITE }}/before/*;

server {
    listen {{ PORT }};
    listen {{ PORT_V6 }};
    server_name {{ DOMAINS }};
    server_tokens off;
    root {{ PATH }};

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/{{ SITE }}/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/{{ SITE }}-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass {{ PROXY_PASS }};
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/{{ SITE }}/after/*;
```

Comment: Are you trying to use laravel forge? If so, it doesn't support something like that out of the box. For regular nginx setup that would be `rewrite ^/register /api/v1/register last;` but for laravel specific way I recommend asking laravel community.

Comment: @palindromeotter33 I didn't think about it... That's the easiest way to do it actually. Thanks for changing my mind ;)